# controlling servos with python - index list out of range

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a python script that is passed two arguments : `servo` and `angle`, where `servo` is the gpio pin used and the `angle` is the amount I wish the servo to turn calculated through PWM.

The issue I am having is that when I run the script i get the error `IndexError: list index out of range` on the line `servo = int(sys.argv[1])`.

I have done some research into this form of error however I am struggling to see the issue within my own code.  Am i trying to access a list that does not exist??

**My code:**

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def setServoAngle(servo, angle):
    assert angle >=30 and angle <= 150
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(servo, 50)
    pwm.start(8)
    dutyCycle = angle / 18. + 3.
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(dutyCycle)
    sleep(0.3)
    pwm.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    servo = int(sys.argv[1])
    GPIO.setup(servo, GPIO.OUT)
    setServoAngle(servo, int(sys.argv[2]))
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: The problem is that you probably don't have any arguments when you call the script or you do it wrong. How do you call the script?

Comment: Are you passing in your arguments when you call the script?  `sys.argv` accesses the command line arguments passed to the script .

Comment: I call the script within another script that links to my html page, the GPIO pins are defined in this script and the angle argument is passed when the user presses the button with their desired angle

Comment: If you are calling from another python script; why are you using `if __name__ == '__main__'` instead of calling a function from the calling script?

Comment: Sorry - for this script i simply run it in the terminal window passing the parameters i.e. sudo python servotest.py 27 45

Comment: If this is your entire code, I do not see where you are `import`ing `sys`

Comment: I tried to import `sys` - however still same error

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - what did you find?